# how to plone view return xml document to request client?

Tags: xml, plone

The wechat server need to receive xml document response from Plone server.
But I don't known to how to return the xml document to the request client.(the wechat server)
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Create a BrowserView, which returns xml, also set the right header for the response.

Register BrowserView with zcml:

```xml
<configure
      xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
      xmlns:browser="http://namespaces.zope.org/browser">

    <browser:page
          for="*"
          permission="zope2.View"
          class=".views.MyViewReturningXML"
          name="my_view.xml"
          />
</configure>
```

The corresponding python code:

```python
from Products.Five.browser import BrowserView
from Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile import ViewPageTemplateFile


class MyViewReturningXML(BrowserView):

    template = ViewPageTemplateFile("my_template.xml")

    def __call__(self):

        # Set header
        self.request.RESPONSE.setHeader("Content-type", "text/xml")

        return self.template()

    #...
    #IMPLEMENTATION
    #....
```

Comment: If you find this answer useful, please accept or add comments, so we can find a suitable solution for you!

Comment: Any news on this one?